# Extra Slash When Using SMTP/Gmail

Tags: python, smtp, sms

I am working to send text messages to my phone using a combination of SMTP and SMS gateways. I have the following lines of code, taken from Alex Le's [blog post on the subject](http://alextrle.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-send-sms-message-with-python.html):

```
import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP( "smtp.gmail.com", 587 )
server.starttls()
server.login( '<gmail_address>', '<gmail_password>' )
server.sendmail( '<from>', '<number>@tmomail.net', '<msg>' )
```

I've tried various different bodies, and two different gmail accounts, but no matter what `<msg>` is preceded by `/`. For example, if the last line was as follows:

```
server.sendmail( 'me', '<number>@tmomail.net', 'Hello, World!' )
```

Then my phone would receive `/ Hello, World!`. Visually, I find this quite annoying. If I had to guess what the problem was, it's that there is a field somewhere that I'm not filling out that the gateway wants to put before the slash, but I don't know what that could be. Ideas?

Comment: It could be something with `tmomail`. I just tried it for att.net, and it looks fine..

Comment: Here: http://wiki.howardforums.com/index.php/T-Mobile_Messaging The slash is to delimit the subject, and body of the email.